# Something about fcitx-table-boshiamy

Tags: input-method

Recently I've installed `fcitx` to replace ibus, but inside this `boshiamy` table, no matter which version, older `0.1.0-1(precise)` or the latest `0.3.1-1(quantal)`, all got the same problem:

> any word with "**z**" as it's code, all couldn't appear normally, the input method will take "z" as "**,**" or "a" sometimes even "**b**"

Could someone try to fix it up?

Answer (score 0):

I'm fcitx dev, I think I fix this in 0.3.2.

Sorry for the inconvenience.

Try manually removing the line with `PY` in `boshiamy.conf` (`/usr/share/fcitx/table`) before the updates hit the repo.

Comment: I did what you've suggested me to do, but nothing changed, use boshiamy you type Z should see "整",and type A+Z will see "之", and I used to use a package https://github.com/vicamo/ibus-table-boshiamy ,bus it's for ibus,pass a while of time,it always will crash down, so fcitx become my last hope!

Comment: I think I found the way!For correcting the problem, I only change the "UseMatchingKey"in boshiamy.conf into "False" or change the"MatchingKey"into other value, such as "," , will just appear correctly those  words with "z"key. But thanks anyway.